# Convert MediaElementAudioSourceNode to AudioBufferSourceNode

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiobuffer

If you want to decode Audio Data, createMediaElementSource() is not working on mobile devices, However createBufferSource() method is working properly:

This code is working properly in web browsers, but not in mobile devices:

```
var audioSource = new Audio();
audioSource.src= "Test.mp3";
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var sourceT1 = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audioSource); //This is the source audio
//My Decoding...
```

And this code is working for both Web and Mobile browsers:

```
var audioSource = new Audio();
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
var sourceT2 = audioCtx.createBufferSource(); //This is the source audio
request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'Test.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
request.onload = function() {
 var audioData = request.response;
audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(myBuffer) {
 sourceT2.buffer = myBuffer;
//My Decoding...
 },
function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
}
```

In my case I have an Audio source that comes from a video player to be decoded, which is a MediaElementAudioSourceNode, and I need to convert it to a AudioBufferSourceNode in order to get my code working on mobile devices, In other words, is it possible to convert **sourceT1** to **sourceT2**?

Any Idea how to do it?

**EDIT:**
Based on this [answer](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-html5/HkX1sP8ONKs), unfortunatly I think it is impossible to do it

Comment: I think as well it's mission impossible as it is not supported.

Comment: Which video files do you need to access? Can u use file-api? What do you want to do with the audio afterwards? Perhaps there is another way...

Comment: I need to get the byte frequency of a remote audio streaming, the problem is that getByteFrequencyData() doesn't work in mobile devices when I create the media by using createMediaElementSource(). Right now I'm trying to find another way, do you know any solution for visualizing frequency of a streaming audio (.m3u8)?

Comment: createMediaElementSource still doesn't seem to work on mobile browsers, 7 years later, but the second method in the post worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say, but if you're using Chrome, createMediaElementSource should be working now.  You have to go to chrome://flags and enable the unified media pipeline flag first, though.

Comment: Do you mean chrome in mobile devices?